# How to place big file on two disks without splitting?

Tags: linux, filesystems, data

I have a file 100gb in size and a server with two 72gb disk's.

The server runs Ubuntu Linux, with ext4 on the disks, and without LVM.

How I can put the 100gb file on the server with 72+72gb disk's?

I can't change the filesystem and I can't split the file; the file must be readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create two ~50GB files, one per disk. Then use `losetup` to map them to loop devices. You can now combine those two loop devices, e.g., with mdraid raid0. Now you can create a filesystem on that array, and finally put your file there.

This is somewhat convoluted, but, well, the right way to do this would be to use LVM and/or mdraid on your two disks if you want to treat them as one.

Example, with much smaller images (and obviously you'll need to use sane paths here, instead of `/tmp` like I did. And probably a better array name than "test"):

```
root@Zia:/tmp# dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/img1 bs=1024k count=1024
⋮
root@Zia:/tmp# dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/img2 bs=1024k count=1024
⋮
root@Zia:/tmp# losetup --show -f /tmp/img1
/dev/loop0
root@Zia:/tmp# losetup -f /tmp/img2
/dev/loop1
root@Zia:/tmp# mdadm -C /dev/md/test -l 0 -n 2 /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md/test started.
root@Zia:/tmp# mkfs.ext4 -Tlargefile4 /dev/md/test 
⋮
root@Zia:/tmp# mount /dev/md/test /mnt/tmp
root@Zia:/tmp# df -h /mnt/tmp/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md126      2.0G  3.0M  1.9G   1% /mnt/tmp
```

And, to put it back together on boot (you'll want to script this, of course):

```
root@Zia:/tmp# losetup --show -f /tmp/img1 
/dev/loop0
root@Zia:/tmp# losetup --show -f /tmp/img2
/dev/loop1
root@Zia:/tmp# mdadm --assemble /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1
mdadm: device /dev/loop0 exists but is not an md array.
root@Zia:/tmp# mdadm --assemble /dev/md/test /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1
mdadm: /dev/md/test has been started with 2 drives.
root@Zia:/tmp# mount /dev/md/test /mnt/tmp
```

Tearing it down before reboot/shutdown will probably just work, but you `umount` it, then `mdadm --stop /dev/md/test`, then `losetup -d` on both of the loop devices.